# Unusual behavior of collectstatic command when use call_command

Tags: python, django, encoding, non-ascii-characters

when using

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

it executes properly but when i do something like

```
call_command('collectstatic', interactive=False)
```

from django shell. It throws an exception

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

DATA USED : static folder containing images with names having characters not in ascii range

Comment: your images' names have some unicode characters. You have to change names

Comment: i noticed that but then why command management executes without throwing exception, and when executed from code snippet using call_command throws exception